# Is it possible to satisfy a __declspec(dllimport) symbol without a dll?

Tags: visual-c++

It's possible to override C runtime functions using the preprocessor (e.g. `/Dfree=my_debug_free`), however having to match the linkage of the redefined symbol is sometimes undesirable or awkward within the context of a given project.

Is there a way to force the dllimport linkage of a symbol to be satisfied with a symbol coming from a static .lib or a .obj?

Let's assume modifying the calling code directly, or defining away the __declspec keyword itself is out of the question.

Comment: The preprocessor definitely won't work as this happens before compilation. I would test a static library, see if that satisfies it it, if not make a mock dll to satisfy it. I know the static library would definitely work on Linux.

Comment: I should clarify, a .dll definitely satisfies it, and is fine to use for some projects, just some others I'm not in a position to introduce a .dll, so I was hoping to "force" the link using a static .lib, however a static .lib doesn't satisfy it (for me) due to the inconsistent linkage. I was hoping there was a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question with what I've found:

One of the things that the __declspec(dllimport) does is say that the function in question has a prefix __imp_ added to it from the importer's point of view, so manually add the prefixed function, and you satisfy the link.

As far as I understand these __imp_ are the bit that the .lib file corresponding to the .dll would normally provide. If you cut out the linking of the .lib for the .dll you cut that those also, and so have to fill in the __imp_ shaped hole manually yourself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(v=vs.60).aspx has a good overview.

All that said, I've found that using a pre-included file (/FI or -include) that #includes the original (unredefined) definitions first, then redefines them with #defines before entering your code works better than using /D to to redefine them everywhere, even in the original definitions. Doing it that way meas you don't need to worry about the .dll stuff.